# GSON object with ResultSet variables

Tags: android, mysql, gson, resultset

i´m parsing a GSON with android, and I want to parse data from my MySQL table. My GSON object is:

```
{"data":
   [
   {"country":"Ireland", "capital": "Dublin"},
     {"country":"Hungary", "capital": "Budapest"},
     {"country":"Democratic Republic of the Congo", "capital": "Kinshasa"}
     ]
   }
```

This object is working for me, i can see this in my phone. Though, if i add to code my resultset from mysql database, like this:

```
<%

    try { Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from capitals");
    while (rs.next()) {                      
        %>             
        {"data":
           [
           {"country":"Ireland", "capital": "<% rs.getString(1); %> "},
             {"country":"Hungary", "capital": "<% rs.getString(2); %>"},
             {"country":"Democratic Republic of the Congo", "capital": "Kinshasa"}
               ]
           }
                            <%
                         }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    %>
```

the applications fails, and shows me "unfortunately, the applications stops." 
Here is my log: http://pastebin.com/8bz5QbjR
It writes, that at line 29 is EOF. Which line? In my Activity(android) or in my GSON object?

Comment: The json you posted is the one you *expect* to produce or your current one? Looking at your code I'm not sure is the one produced.

Comment: The first json is an example, which works for me. The second one(in jsp code) is the code, which i expect...so instead of rs.getString(1) i wanna here the name of the capital city from my mysql table...